# Windows C++ framework recommendation

Tags: c++, winapi, frameworks

Does anyone know of a good C++ framework for Windows? I don't need it for GUI, but for some kind of a WINAPI C++ wrapper. I don't like MFC, and ATL is quite limited. These possibilities are nice, but its not wrapped enough, and in the end I always find wrap WINAPI myself.

Does anyone know of a good framework?

Comment: The Windows API is quite large. Do you want it for something specific like filesystem, processes & threads, registry & INI files, services, network, or? I like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) :)

Comment: You don't need it for GUI. What functionality *do* you need?

Comment: What kind of wrapper would you need for non-GUI WinAPI, other than a scope guard, anyway?

Comment: I need to for stuff like registry, windows security, user/groups, impersonations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most important non-GUI API tasks (files, network, threading), `boost` does a pretty good job.

Comment: I'm using boost and it is great, but there are lots of other things, like registry, tokens, users, processes etc.

Comment: Although its still miss many windows-specific things, its still the best I've found.

Answer (score 1):

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) wraps a lot of functionality in a nice C++ api.